# WPF: Got Unable to cast object exception when try to convert

Tags: wpf, textblock, ivalueconverter

I try to convert simple `string` and add markup `string` for example:

```
Value is: bla bla
```

into: `Value is <Span Foreground="Red">bla bla</Span>`

So i want to use `MultiValueConverter` and add simple converter (so far without any implementation):

```
public class StatusConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Window.Resources:

```
    <my:StatusConverter x:Key="StatusConverterToColor"/>
```

Usage:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusConverterToColor}}" />
```

But got this error:

> {"Unable to cast object of type
>   'MyApplication.classes.StatusConverter' to type
>   'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'."}

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Change `IMultiValueConverter` to `IValueConverter`. Declaration should be

```
public class StatusConverter : IValueConverter
{ ... }
```

Comment: And with IValueConverter i will be able to change my string and add this markup ?

Comment: Yes it should, as soon as provided real implementation inside `Convert` method instead of throwing `NotImplementedException`